# MVC3 - razor: error while passing query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm a new bie with MVC3 razor. Can anyone please help me why I am getting this error on run.

**Error:**
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
it breaks on ActionLink.

**HTML Code:**

```
@model Solution.User

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@id = "name-ref", @class = "text size-40"})
    @Html.ActionLink("Go Ahead", "Index", "Home", new {name = Model.name, @class = "button" })
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    return View();
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't supplied a model to the view.

Define a class to act as the view model

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in your controller's action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(User model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

MVC's model binder will automatically create an instance for the parameter `model` and bind the `name` value to `User.Name` for you.

**Edit** Your view mentions a model called `User`. I changed my answer to reflect that.